# What is the derivative of $\mbox{trace} (\Sigma^.5 S^{-1}\Sigma^.5)$ with respect to $\Sigma$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

While fitting a Gaussian distribution to another Gaussian, I came up with this term

$$\mbox{trace} (\Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}} S^{-1}\Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}})$$

I need to compute its derivative with respect to $\Sigma$. Both $\Sigma$ and $S$ are positive definite matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trace of product is invariant under cyclic permutations of the product.  Thus

$\mbox{tr}(\Sigma^{1/2}S^{-1}\Sigma^{1/2})=\mbox{tr}(\Sigma^{1/2}\Sigma^{1/2}S^{-1})=\mbox{tr}(\Sigma S^{-1})$

The derivative of $\mbox{tr}(\Sigma S^{-1})$ with respect to $\Sigma$ is $S^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
$$
\operatorname{trace}(\Sigma^{1/2}S^{-1}\Sigma^{1/2}) = 
\operatorname{trace}(S^{-1}\Sigma)
$$
It should be straightforward to compute this derivative, what ever your method.

Comment: Ohh. Thanks. That was obvious. Sorry!